# error in running .phar php application

Tags: php, phar, jelastic

I'm trying to use .phar extension for deploy PHP project, but I get the following error:

```
apache@apache2 ~/webroot/phpDox $ php phpdox.phar --version
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/Phar.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/Phar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
phpDox 0.8.0 - Copyright (C) 2010 - 2015 by Arne Blankerts

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/Phar.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/Phar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

No stacktrace available
```

I am using apache 2.4.6 with PHP 5.4 in my Jelastic environment.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
How can I solve this problem?
```

You should to connect to environment via SSH and perform the following:

**cd webroot/ROOT/**

**curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php**

**php composer.phar install**

That's all. After this you will have the Composer dependencies manager at your ROOT directory. Then you should to ensure that the index page (index.php) is contains the loader string like require "../vendor/autoload.php" that is needed for automatic downloading and enabling of the necessary libs.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But I still having the same error.

Comment: @DKay, could you please tell if you included that module into the php.ini extensions manually?

Comment: @Aless, yes, I have included it in php.ini

Comment: @DKay, looks like you added this module into the php.ini extensions without adding the dynamic library into the modules folder. Please, read an article [Jelastic PHP Modules](https://docs.jelastic.com/php-extensions) for understanding how you can set different PHP extensions into the Jelastic cloud.

FYI, the Phar module is included into the PHP by default since version 5.3 and not needed for the adding it manually.